# Vertex label to change from id to another column in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I am creating a graph that's taking the id as vertex names. However I want to change the vertex label to another column values. How can I do that?

Columns in df1 are ID, name and I want the vertex labels to be name

My code:

```
df1:
ID  NAME
1   Ada
2   Cora
3   Louise
            
df2:
SOURCE  TARGET  TYPE       ID  WEIGHT
1       2       DIRECTED   2   2   
1       3       DIRECTED   1   2
2       1       DIRECTED   3   1



  g = graph.data.frame(d = df2, directed = TRUE, vertices = df1);    
    V(g)$size<-degree(g)
        plot(g,                
             layout=layout.circle, main="circle", 
             vertex.label.dist=0.4,          
             vertex.label=V(g)$id,      
             vertex.label.cex=1, edge.arrow.size=0.
```

Thanks

Comment: Please use `dput(df1)` and `dput(df2)` to share you data in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
g %>%
    set_vertex_attr(
        name = "name",
        value = V(.)$NAME
    )
```

which gives

```
IGRAPH 19e91db DN-- 3 3 --
+ attr: name (v/c), NAME (v/c), TYPE (e/c), ID (e/n), WEIGHT (e/n)
+ edges from 19e91db (vertex names):
[1] Ada ->Cora   Ada ->Louise Cora->Ada
```